# Are Android's Parcelables supported by Scala?

Tags: android, scala, parcelable

I've read that due to Scala compiler magic it is possible to implement the Android Parcelable pattern in Scala (that requires a static class member). However there is very little information about that and I'm not sure ...

- ... if this is even true
- ... if I have to take care of something (e.g. setting compiler flags?)
- ... where the `CREATOR` field goes (class or companion?) and how to define it (def, val, var?)

I tried various combinations but always ended up with an exception telling me, that the `CREATOR` field is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in Scala 2.11.2 the `CREATOR` field goes into the companion object:

```
class ParcelExample( val some: String, val arbitrary: Int, val values: Boolean ) extends Parcelable
{
    override def describeContents() = 0

    override def writeToParcel( dest: Parcel, flags: Int )
    {
        dest.writeString( some )
        dest.writeInt( arbitrary )
        dest.writeValue( values )
    }
}

object ParcelExample
{
    val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator[ParcelExample] = new Parcelable.Creator[ParcelExample]
    {
        override def createFromParcel( source: Parcel ): ParcelExample = new ParcelExample(
            source.readString(),
            source.readInt(),
            source.readValue( classOf[Boolean].getClassLoader ).asInstanceOf[Boolean]
        )

        override def newArray( size: Int ): Array[ParcelExample] = new Array[ParcelExample]( size )
    }
}
```

I created a scala macro that genereates the parcelable boilerplate https://github.com/taig/parcelable

Answer (score 1):

In general, creating static fields is impossible in Scala. However, the `CREATOR` field needed for `Parcelable` has been special-cased in the compiler. Simply declare a `val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator[YourClassNameHere]` in the class itself and it will be implemented as a static field.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/xuwei-k/2555107) for a complete example.

Comment: I've seen that Gist before but failed to make it work. I'll give it another try with a more simple example tonight.

Comment: I had no luck with that approach, however placing the CREATOR in the companion object works. I probably messed it up with inheritance when I tried this before.

Comment: Strange, I tested with 2.11 before posting and with CREATOR declared in the class itself I got a static field.

Comment: For me it seems, when I add the Parcelable interface Scala creates a static CREATOR field that references the companion object and expects to find a user defined CREATOR field there. At least that's what I got from fiddling around with `javap`. When I add a CREATOR field to the class it will be non static - but the static one will still be around (throwing errors because there is no companion).